# Enum generation using JavaPoet

Tags: java, enums, javapoet

How to generate the following enum class using JavaPoet?

```
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY (3, 2),
    VENUS   (4, 6)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
TypeSpec planetTypeSpec = 
 TypeSpec.enumBuilder("Planet")
      .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
      .addEnumConstant("MERCURY", TypeSpec.anonymousClassBuilder("$L, $L",3,2).build())
      .addEnumConstant("VENUS", TypeSpec.anonymousClassBuilder("$L, $L",4,6).build())
      .build();
```

Comment: how to add javadoc on EnumConstant?

Comment: gotta:
`.addEnumConstant("VENUS", TypeSpec.anonymousClassBuilder("").addJavadoc("some doc").build())`